# Rails not logging in development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

I have a Rails2 application that works great on 2 servers.
It is configured in development mode on both sides.

On one server it stopped logging informations and I cannot figure out why.
I've tried to remove development.log file, but didn't change nothing.

This is the content of environments/development.rb:

```
config.cache_classes = false

# Log error messages when you accidentally call methods on nil.
config.whiny_nils = true

# Show full error reports and disable caching
config.action_controller.consider_all_requests_local = true
config.action_view.debug_rjs                         = true
config.action_controller.perform_caching             = false

# Don't care if the mailer can't send
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
Sass::Plugin.options[:debug_info] = true
```

Comment: Does it definitely have permission to log to the log directory? Have you tried restarting the rails server?

Comment: Yes, I've tried to restart the entire machine and the apache web server. If I run commands from the console, they get logged into the development.log file..